# Restricting an arrays of strings or adding extra symbols to it

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'd like to create a program that given a pair of strings, would either restrict them or add extra characters depending upon the length which is provided in the pair. For example, it should behave as:

```
 create (new Line[] {"try","chicken"},
 new Couple[] {new Couple(’t’,3),new Couple(’c’,3)})
```

should return

```
{"try", "chi"}
```

The above is when the length(number specified) is less than or equal to the word given. 
The below is an example of what if the length is greater than the word.

```
create (new Line[] {"try","chicken"},
new Couple[] {new Couple(’t’,3),new Couple(’c’,9)})
```

should return

```
{"try", "chickenPP"}
```

That is we replace the remaining spaces by the letter P.

Here's what i tried:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Learn {

    private char firstChar;
    private int length;
    private char chars;
    private char FILL_CHARACTER = 'P';

    public Learn(char firstChar, int length, char chars) {
        this.length = length;
        this.firstChar = firstChar;
        this.chars = chars;
    }

    public static String[] create(String[] first, Couple[] second) {
        String[] strings = new String[first.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
            if (second.length = first.chars) {
               learns[i] = first[i];
            } else if (second.length > first.chars) {
                   learns[i] = first[i] + FILL_CHARACTER;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, i have lots of errors. I guess i'm getting confused with the API maybe. Please help me correct it.

Comment: So `Line` is really `String`, and `Couple` is an ignored character along with the integer length, and `Learn` is also `String`?  What are you trying to accomplish with the extra classes?

Comment: I've edited the above post..does it help? :(

Comment: What is the Class Couple? Why do you have a class Learn that you don't use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing with `Learn` and `Couple`, but you can do it all via `String`s:

```
public static String[] create(String[] words,int[] lengths) {
    char fill = 'P';
    String[] ret = new String[words.length];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < ret.length ; i++ ) {
    ret[i] = words[i];
    while ( ret[i].length() < lengths[i] ) {
        ret[i] += fill;
    }
    ret[i] = ret[i].substring(0,lengths[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

use:
`create(new String[]{"try","chicken"},new int[]{3,3});`